# Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin

Tags: java, spring, maven

I'm getting this error while doing `mvn clean install`
this error happened just after integrating sonarqube.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.4:run (default)
> on project bootloader: Unable to parse configuration of mojo
> org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.4:run for
> parameter include: Cannot find default setter in class org
> .springframework.boot.maven.Include -> [Help 1]

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>io.releve</groupId>
<artifactId>releveproject</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<modules>
    <module>application</module>
    <module>bootloader</module>
    <module>domain</module>
    <module>infrastructure</module>

</modules>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>


<properties>
    <application.name.value>relevebancaire</application.name.value>
    <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-boot.version>2.1.3.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
        <sonar.organization>ibrahimbakhaled</sonar.organization>
        <sonar.host.url>https://sonarcloud.io</sonar.host.url>
    <sonar.exclusions>
        **/*BootloaderApplicationLauncher.java,
        **/*Configuration.java,
        **/config/**,
        **/domain/**,
        **/adapter/**,
        **/entity/**,
        **/repository/**,
        **/api/**,
        **/**Test**/**,
        **/cdg.releve/**
    </sonar.exclusions>
    <sonar.jdbc.dialect>mysql</sonar.jdbc.dialect>
    <sonar.projectName>${application.name.value}</sonar.projectName>
    <sonar.projectVersion>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</sonar.projectVersion>
    <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
    <sonar.binaries>build/classes</sonar.binaries>
    <sonar.sources>src</sonar.sources>
    <sonar.tests>src/test</sonar.tests>
    <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
    <sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>
</properties>

<build>

        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                    </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0.905</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>sonar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: You are mixing different spring boot versions... spring-boot-starter-web 2.6.3 while the version property for spring boot is set to 2.1.3.RELEASE...you should first clean that up....the spring-boot-maven-plugin is version 2.6.4 and the question why do you need the given include configuration which does not make sense?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using inconsistent versions of Spring Boot and Spring
Framework.  I suggest getting more of your dependencies from
`spring-boot-dependencies`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>io.releve</groupId>
<artifactId>releveproject</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<modules>
    <module>application</module>
    <module>bootloader</module>
    <module>domain</module>
    <module>infrastructure</module>
</modules>

<properties>
    <application.name.value>relevebancaire</application.name.value>
    <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-boot.version>2.1.3.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
        <sonar.organization>ibrahimbakhaled</sonar.organization>
        <sonar.host.url>https://sonarcloud.io</sonar.host.url>
    <sonar.exclusions>
        **/*BootloaderApplicationLauncher.java,
        **/*Configuration.java,
        **/config/**,
        **/domain/**,
        **/adapter/**,
        **/entity/**,
        **/repository/**,
        **/api/**,
        **/**Test**/**,
        **/cdg.releve/**
    </sonar.exclusions>
    <sonar.jdbc.dialect>mysql</sonar.jdbc.dialect>
    <sonar.projectName>${application.name.value}</sonar.projectName>
    <sonar.projectVersion>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</sonar.projectVersion>
    <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
    <sonar.binaries>build/classes</sonar.binaries>
    <sonar.sources>src</sonar.sources>
    <sonar.tests>src/test</sonar.tests>
    <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
    <sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>


<build>

        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                    </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0.905</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>sonar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Note the reduced dependency management and the version used for
`spring-boot-maven-plugin`.

You can further reduce the size/complexity of your POM if you use
`spring-boot-dependencies` as your parent POM:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>io.releve</groupId>
<artifactId>releveproject</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
  </parent>
<modules>
    <module>application</module>
    <module>bootloader</module>
    <module>domain</module>
    <module>infrastructure</module>
</modules>

<properties>
    <application.name.value>relevebancaire</application.name.value>
    <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <sonar.organization>ibrahimbakhaled</sonar.organization>
        <sonar.host.url>https://sonarcloud.io</sonar.host.url>
    <sonar.exclusions>
        **/*BootloaderApplicationLauncher.java,
        **/*Configuration.java,
        **/config/**,
        **/domain/**,
        **/adapter/**,
        **/entity/**,
        **/repository/**,
        **/api/**,
        **/**Test**/**,
        **/cdg.releve/**
    </sonar.exclusions>
    <sonar.jdbc.dialect>mysql</sonar.jdbc.dialect>
    <sonar.projectName>${application.name.value}</sonar.projectName>
    <sonar.projectVersion>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</sonar.projectVersion>
    <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
    <sonar.binaries>build/classes</sonar.binaries>
    <sonar.sources>src</sonar.sources>
    <sonar.tests>src/test</sonar.tests>
    <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
    <sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>
</properties>

<build>

        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                    </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0.905</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>sonar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

This technique allows you to override Spring Boot dependency version
properties defined in `spring-boot-dependencies` simply by defining the same
property in you POM `<properties/>` with the version you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot find default setter in class org.springframework.boot.maven.Include

The error message gives you the hint what is wrong.

The `include` element should contain `groupId` and `artifactId` instead of `**/*Test.java` (are you putting something wrong here?) according to [spring boot maven plugin document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#goals-repackage-parameters-details-includes), so the pom should look like

```xml
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
                <includes>
                    <include>
                        <groupId>some-groupId</groupId>
                        <artifactId>some-artifactId</artifactId>
                    </include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I just solved it, removed those includes tags and after there was an error of sonarscanner which needs java 11 to analyze and fixed that. All worked Thanks.